# I have 2 questions. 1: Is it possible to generate an array of random numbers, with every number to distinct, say 10 numbers in range of 0 and 1000?

Tags: solidity, oracles, randomness, gambling

I know, that using block hash or timestamp is not secure for gambling applications, and I know that I can use Oraclize to get a real random number. 
But is it possible to ask for an array of distinct numbers?

Also, even I am getting a number from Oraclize, the miners can throw the block away in the same way, until they are satisfied with the random isn't it true? So what sense of using Oraclize then? many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If a miner throws away a block, they also throw away their reward. The economical incentive would need to be really high for them to discard a block like that. But that wouldn't help anyway with Oraclize - they send the data to the blockchain and some miner mines it anyway.

I guess you can also ask for an array of numbers from Oraclize, but really can't tell for sure what all they support - ask in their support forums for more info if you're unsure.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I have posted an entry in Oraclize GitHub repository.

Comment: But still can't understand why Oraclize can't be tricked in the same way, and miners just would not throw a block away.